# Directional derivative zero, minimum and convexity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, examples-counterexamples

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be convex, let $u\in \mathbb R^n$,  $v\in \mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$ and assume that the directional derivative of $f$ at $u$ in direction $v$ is $0$.

I'm wondering if this implies that $f$ has a global minimum at $x$.
The function $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R, t\mapsto f(x+tv)$ is convex and its right-derivative at $0$ is zero, hence $g$ has a global minimum at $0$, thus $f$ is minimized at $x$ **when restricted along direction $v$**.

I don't see a reason why $x$ should be a global minimizer. Can someone provide a counterexample ?

Comment: $f(x, y) = x$ is convex, and the directional derivative in $y$-direction is zero ...

Comment: @MartinR Silly me ! Please post this as an answer.

Comment: If all directional derivatives at $u$ are $\ge0$ then you have a minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A counterexample: $f(x, y) = x$ is convex, and the directional derivative in $y$-direction is zero everywhere. But $f$ has no (local or global) minimum at all.

If $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable then a *necessary* condition for a (local or global) minimum at a point $x_0$ is that $\nabla f(x_0) = 0$. For a convex function this condition is also *sufficient* for a global minimum.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments with $f(x, y) = x$ and $v$ going in the $y$-direction, there are plenty of very accessible counterexamples.

In fact, if $g:\Bbb R^m\to \Bbb R^n$ with $m>n$ is differentiable, then there *has* to be, at every single point of $\Bbb R^m$, directions where the directional derivative of $g$ is zero. And yet clearly not every function has local minima or maxima (the above counterexample generalizes neatly to any dimension).

We can probably see this fact most easily if we consider the derivative of $g$ at a point $u$ as a linear transformation $J$. (This is the so-called *Jacobian* of $g$ at $u$, and its matrix form, assuming a Cartesian coordinate system on $\Bbb R^m$ and $\Bbb R^n$, has as columns all the partial derivatives of $g$. In the special case of $n = 1, m>1$ the Jacobian is often called the *gradient*, and in the special case $m = 1, n>1$ it is called the velocity vector.) Then the directional derivative at $u$ in the direction of $v$ is $Jv$. And since $J$ is a linear transformation from $m$-dimensional space to $n$-dimensional space, if $m>n$ then $J$ must have a non-trivial kernel.

Comment: The definition of the Jacobian (which is often also denoted as $D$ for "total derivative") of $g$ at $u$ is the unique linear map such that the approximation
$$
g(u + v) \approx g(u) + Jv
$$
has an error that is "significantly" smaller than $\|v\|$ for small $\|v\|$. You can recognize the elements from the classic definition of the derivative of a function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ at $x$, which is (not exactly, but close enough to) $$f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$ by shuffling around the terms a little.

Comment: You can also show this by taking a tangent plane (if you have more dimensions, you can take a two-dimensional subset of the tangent space), then defining a function $g(\theta)$ as being the directional derivative in the $\theta$ direction. Take a $\theta_0$ such that $g(\theta_0) \neq 0$ (if there are none, then we're done). Now, $g(\pi+\theta_0) = -g(\theta)$, so either $g(\theta_0)  < 0 < g(\pi+\theta_0)$ or $g(\pi+\theta_0)  < 0 < g(\theta_0)$. By the continuity of the derivative and the MVT, there is some $\theta_1$ such that $g(\theta_1)=0$.